# Stipulating how Excel treats data when I export it into R?

Tags: r, excel

I am using huxtable to process data so that it is formatted in the same way to a pre-existing publication. When I export the data to Excel, however, my data appears with decimal points (it appears correctly in r). How do I get Excel to read the data exactly as it appears in r? Is there a way of coding in stipulations for how Excel reads your data into r?

Thanks and sorry if this has been asked before, I had a look and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Could you write it out of R as a .csv file and then open it in Excel that way? Using `write.csv()`.  Excel handles csv files easily enough. I am not sure if this is an option but throwing this out there anyway.

Comment: I can’t - using R to create formatting that doesn’t carry over into csv, unfortunately

Comment: `huxtable::as_Workbook` might work with `openxlsx` installed first too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `number_format`? If that doesn't work you might want to file an issue at https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable/issues. (Disclaimer: I wrote the package.)

Example:

```
library(huxtable)
foo <- as_huxtable(matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2))
number_format(foo) <- 0   # zero decimal places
as_Workbook(foo)          # should have the right formatting
```